# Console logs for the nginx ui service in Openshift written in Zulu time stamp - want them in EST

Tags: openshift, redhat, kubernetes-helm, odk

If i check the logs of the pod which is of type nginx ui service in Openshift i see that it is getting written in Zulu time stamp. How do i change that to EST?

for example:

2020/01/06 **19:00:22** [notice] 1#0: using the "poll" event method
2020/01/06 **19:00:22** [notice] 1#0: nginx/1.12.1
2020/01/06 **19:00:22** [notice] 1#0: built by gcc 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16) (GCC) 
2020/01/06 **19:00:22** [notice] 1#0: OS: Linux 3.10.0-1062.1.1.el7.x86_64

Comment: Try setting the TZ environment variable: `oc set env RESOURCE/NAME DC TZ=America/New_York`

Comment: Thanks i went ahead and updated the deployments.yaml with the TZ env property and it worked.